# Laravel 5.0.* artisan giving warnings

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.0 on PHP 5.6

Running this command

```
php artisan
```

Giving this error

[image: error message]

I tried the following things:

- tried to run with php 7.o
- checked routes
- cleared cache

but problem not solved.

Error is also not being written to logs directory. Can anybody tell me where may be the problem? I am stuck on this from last 10 hours.

Comment: You have something in `database/migration`? This is new project?

Comment: no this is old project

Comment: So you have some files in `database/migration`?

Comment: yes i have.. ..

Answer (score 0):

Is this a new project or a old one? Why are you using Laravel 5.0? It does not support PHP7 very well, upgrade to at least 5.1 LTS or Laravels latest stable version.

I can't see the entire error message but it seems like it might be an error due to an argument being passed when routing. Try to temporary remove various routes and identify if any one of them is causing the problem. You might need to do the following after removing the routes:

`php artisan route:cache`

You can also try the following command to see if it solves your problem:

`composer dump-autoload`

Also you can try creating a new Laravel project and see if the same problem remains, so that you can be sure that it's something inside that project and not your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try running from powershell, GitBash may be having a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

well i had used the url() function in one of my config file.. that was creating issues.. after removing it.. app is working fine now..